Built a custom related list LWC: any way to create a custom quick link?
I built a custom LWC that works like a related list, mostly based on this code: https://medium.com/@terrasky_thailand/try-creating-a-related-list-like-component-using-lightning-web-components-c584f96ed523
I did not use the lightning-ui-related-list-api because I'm querying child object records that are not directly related to the parent object record.
Would there be any way to create a related list quick link that would work like the standard ones for the standard related lists, where the user could hover over the link to see the first few records, then click on to go to the main related list?

